# PDFCreator COM Script Run as Service Fails to see Jobs Printed

Tags: vbscript, com

I have a PDFCreator script I compiled in PrimalScript so that I could execute it via svrany and the problem I am running into is the fact that when I run the service the print jobs from the script are never seen by the queue. If I run the vbscript or the compiled exe from my session it works fine.

Here is the code in my vbs file that runs against pdfcreator version 2.1.1.820

```
Dim strExt, intStatus, strDestFileName, strInputFileName, strReason 


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set PDFCreatorQueue = CreateObject("PDFCreatorBeta.JobQueue")

strInputFileName = "C:\Temp\Test.txt" 
strDestFileName = "C:\Temp\Test.pdf"

PDFProcess 

' ** Sub Routine to render file as PDF
Sub PDFProcess  
Dim objFolder, job, intStatPDFCreator, intPageCount

intPageCount = 1  

WScript.Echo "PDF Destination Name: " & strDestFile 
WScript.Echo "Initializing PDFCreator queue..."
intStatPDFCreator = PDFCreatorQueue.Initialize()
WScript.Echo "PDFCreator Object Status: " & intStatPDFCreator 

If intStatPDFCreator = 0 Then 
        If Not objFSO.FileExists(strInputFileName) Then
            WScript.Echo "PDFCreator: Can't find the file: " & strInputFileName
        Else 
            WScript.Echo "Printing Page: " & strInputFileName 

            objShell.ShellExecute strInputFileName, "", "", "print"

            WScript.Sleep 1000
            WScript.Echo "Currently there are " & PDFCreatorQueue.Count & " job(s) in the queue" 
        End If

    WScript.Echo "Waiting for the job to arrive at the queue..."
    if Not(PDFCreatorQueue.WaitForJobs(intPageCount, 10)) Then 
        strReason = "The print job did not reach the queue within " & 10 & " seconds" 
        WScript.Echo strReason 
        intStatus = 0
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Currently there are " & PDFCreatorQueue.Count & " job(s) in the queue" 
        WScript.Echo "Getting job instance and merging"

        PDFCreatorQueue.MergeAllJobs

        while(PDFCreatorQueue.Count > 0)
            Set job = PDFCreatorQueue.NextJob
                WScript.Echo "Staging PDF File: " & strDestFileName 
            job.ConvertTo(strDestFileName)
                WScript.sleep 5000

            If Not(job.IsFinished Or job.IsSuccessful) Then
                strReason = "Could not convert the file: " & strDestFileName
                    WScript.Echo strReason 
                intStatus = 0
            Else
                WScript.Echo "Job finished successfully" 
            End If 
        Wend 
    End If 
        WScript.Echo "Releasing the object"
    PDFCreatorQueue.ReleaseCom()
Else
    strReason =  "Failed to create PDFCreator COM instance."
        WScript.Echo strReason 
    intStatus = 0
End If


End Sub
```

The service I have running under my domain credentials and have modified the registry to allow it to run interactively

```
SERVICE_NAME: tgprintprocessor
    TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  (interactive)
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
    PID                : 3752
    FLAGS              :
```

I have set interactive Services Detection to a running state.

reviewing the PDFCreator trace log I don't see any errors of any kind.

If I open PDFCreator printer and view the print queue, I do see the job hit the queue and exit, and can even pause the printer so the job stops in the printer queue but the com object queue is oblivious to its existence.

I also tried running PDFCreator.exe additionally as a service incase it needed to have an instance of the exe running in the background as I noticed the application itself does not fire up in task manager post print job submission like I typically see when executing the script manually.

What is my question, I guess I don't know where else to look and if there is maybe something I am missing that I can add to the above test script to attempt trapping the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution to this issue and behavior above is to change the driver isolation mode from the default NONE, to SHARED. I did this under Print Management Snapin. Took a while to figure it out....

Comment: A little more info: You will need to add the Print Server role via Server Manager to the computer in order to get the Print Management snap-in. (Also, big +1. There are many people with this same question across the internet, but this is the only solution I've seen that doesn't require upgrading PDFCreator or fragile hacks.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WScript it will stop at the first wscript.echo. Make sure you are running with CScript.

Comment: compiled exe is executing in cscript and I have verified via task manager that cscript initializes the call to the vbs file.

Comment: `sc config UI0Detect start= auto
sc start UI0Detect
rundll32 winsta.dll,WinStationSwitchToServicesSession` That's three lines. The last line will switch you to the services desktop.

Comment: at the time of the service executing and processing input files there are no programs requiring attention or input of any kind.

Comment: That's not the message I get if nothing is happening. You need to put logging into your file.

Comment: have logging enabled, my actual script above is just a dumbed down version of what I am actually using, I have a function that replaces each of those wscript.echo entries. I also have the PDFCreator Debug log enabled on TRACE Mode, WIndows Print service Admin and Operational log enabled. Not sure what else I can log that would indicate the point of failure here...